# PHP Facebook API Cursor Based Pagination

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, pagination

I am trying to page through data I received via the facebook graph API. Facebook recommends doing cursor-based pagination. I am assuming this means retrieving more data as you scroll down with the cursor? I have looked at several examples and am confused how to do this. My Facebook API call returns a similar format to the example below

```
  {
  "data": [
     ... Endpoint data is here
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "after": "MTAxNTExOTQ1MjAwNzI5NDE=",
      "before": "NDMyNzQyODI3OTQw"
    },
    "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?limit=25&before=NDMyNzQyODI3OTQw"
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?limit=25&after=MTAxNTExOTQ1MjAwNzI5NDE="
  }
}
```

I have been able to traverse additional pages using the "next" and "previous", but I do not know how to use the "before" and "after" to do cursor based paging. Here is the Facebook link which encourages cursor based paging and information about its parameters.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.1

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You do a request to the url that is listed in previous or next depending in which direction you want to go

Comment: Yea, I have done that as a temporary solution. But I am trying to do cursor based paging, where as I scroll down additional data is shown. The Facebook link I provided above suggests it has something to do with the "before" and "after"

Comment: If you look at the link the next link just contain the after cursor. And the previous link contains the before cursor. I don't know why we give you both

Comment: Okay cool. Do you know how I set it up to do it based on scrolling? Right now I just code it to open up a set number when the page is loaded

Comment: Write some javascript code that tracks the scroll and loads more when needed